# setHttpMethod weird behaviour

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurlconnection, nsmutableurlrequest, http-method

I am facing a weird problem in downloading xml files from server.

I am trying to get schedulist.xml using the following code,

```
- (void) downloadXml:(NSString*)url {

_urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

    [_urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

       if(_urlConnection !=NULL)
        return NO;

    _urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:_urlRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

}
```

The problem is ,

1. When internet is available , If I click the button to download xml,Fine. Xml is getting downloaded.
2. Turned off the internet now, If I click the button again, it is calling `didReceiveResponse,didReceiveData and connectionDidFinishLoading.` FYI , I have deleted the old response data.

But the thing is , If I use `[_urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];` It is working fine, which is

1. Working fine with internet
2. `didFailWithError` is getting called

What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `NSURLRequest` uses protocol data to decide whether to cache request or not.
For example, if "Cache-control" or "Expires" directives are present in response headers ([RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)), their values will be used to decide if cached response can be used as it is.
Usually only GET requests are cached, that's why you get `didFailWithError` on your `POST` request.
To avoid caching you can fix headers on your server or set `cachePolicy` property of `NSURLRequest` to `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData`

Comment: Yo man. That was absolutely perfect. Thanks for the description about GET . :) Thank you again